# Bonjour SDK/Reference in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2015, uwp, zeroconf

Can I use Bonjour SDK in an universal app? I'm having trouble to add Bonjour reference in my Visual Studio. I did install Bonjour SDK on my machine.

The closest question I can find is this. It is a one year old question and being left without a proper answer.

[Bonjour SDK for Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522378/bonjour-sdk-for-windows-8-1)

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to develop an universal application with .Net framework 4.5.2.

I can run the simplechat sample from Bonjour SDK and it generates a interop.Bonjour.dll. In the solution, there is a Bonjour reference pointing to that dll file. How can I do the same thing in Visual Studio 2015?

If this is not possible, is there any alternative? Please bear in mind I also need to implement the same feature for an iOS/OSX and maybe an Android.

**Edit:** The app should be able to detect and talk to each other on different platforms.

**Edit:** Would multicast be another solution?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is designed for Classic Windows Apps, not for UWP or StoreApps.

But, You can find several alternatives that enable to use the bonjour features from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Bonjour).

In my case, following nuget PCL package works well for both Win8.1 and Windows Phone8.1 storeapps. I haven't tried yet with UWP.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zeroconf/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm being skeptical about using some third party libraries like that. 2k downloads so far and most of them have been updated for years.